# How can my button's position be centered without any kind of "margin cheat"?

Tags: html, css

How can I place my button in the center without any kind of "margin cheat" (for example setting `margin-left: 525px;`)?

**HTML**

```
<div id="banner">
    <div id="bannerContainer">
        <h1>H1 tag</h1>
        <a href="#" class="bannerButton">Products</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .bannerButton {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(63, 127, 191);
    padding: 18px 60px 18px 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 525px;
}
.bannerButton:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #eaf;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I've tried making it sit in the center but it didn't work out so well without me setting `margin-left; 525px;`, which in my case, centers the button under the text, please help me remove this "margin cheat" and do it in the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `a` act like text it means when you give `text-align:center;` to its parent, it will be placed in center of its parent.

You don't need to give `margin` to the `a` element. You can use `text-align:center;`.

```css
#bannerContainer
{
  text-align:center;
}

    .bannerButton {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(63, 127, 191);
    padding: 18px 60px 18px 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
.bannerButton:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #eaf;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
    <div id="bannerContainer">
        <h1>H1 tag</h1>
        <a href="#" class="bannerButton">Products</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, I used the center tag and it actually worked :D

Comment: @JamesSnowy Please, read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center): `<center>` is Deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for noticing me, I didn't have know that the <center> tag wasn't supported by the majority of the web browsers, thanks again, I would have done a mistake if you hadn't notified me.

Comment: @JamesSnowy Simpily, remove the `h1` alignment. I update my answer.

Comment: @JamesSnowy Does it fix your problem?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that when I tried your code, I didn't need to set an alignment to the H1 tag as nothing happened when I gave the #bannerContainer an alignment, thanks for the help, really appreciated it.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the position of the button to absolute, give it a set width, and add this it should center:

```
left: 50%; right: 50%;
```

Comment: Thanks for the spending time on this answer, I tried with the <center> tag in HTML and it actually worked.

Comment: @JamesSnowy If you wanted a CSS answer, text-align: center; would also work probably. You may have to place it on the parent though

Comment: Yeah, I did the thing Alireza was stating, it worked.

Comment: @JamesSnowy Oh I didn't see that answer. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this:

```
<center><a href="#" class="bannerButton">Products</a></center>
```

I am not sure whether it is helpful to you..

Comment: The <center> tag you gave me actually worked, thanks for the help man!

Comment: The center tag worked in google chrome, but it's outdated and the majority of the browsers can break the tag, just to notify you :)